# How to group datas in a list of dict by keys?

Tags: json, list, dataframe, dictionary, group-by

I have a list of dictionaries, each one related to one student. I want to create a table grouped by each course by semester and have the mean of values related to each line.

course - semester - mean

When I use the function .groupby() it doesn't work but I can't find what to do.

Extrait of my list :

```
[{'matricule': '22000803', 'nom': 'Boyer,AndrÃ©', 'note': 'C+', 'valeur': 2.3, 'titre': 'La cybersÃ©curitÃ© et le gestionnaire', 'sigle': 'TECH 20701', 'trimestre': 'H2005'},
 {'matricule': '22000829', 'nom': 'Keighan,Maylis', 'note': 'A+', 'valeur': 4.3, 'titre': 'La cybersÃ©curitÃ© et le gestionnaire', 'sigle': 'TECH 20701', 'trimestre': 'H2005'},
 {'matricule': '22000869', 'nom': 'Lahaie,Lyes', 'note': 'B+', 'valeur': 3.3, 'titre': 'La cybersÃ©curitÃ© et le gestionnaire', 'sigle': 'TECH 20701', 'trimestre': 'H2005'},
 {'matricule': '22000973', 'nom': 'Conerardy,Rawaa', 'note': 'B+', 'valeur': 3.3, 'titre': 'La cybersÃ©curitÃ© et le gestionnaire', 'sigle': 'TECH 20701', 'trimestre': 'H2005'},
 {'matricule': '22001034', 'nom': 'Naftanaila,Carla', 'note': 'B+', 'valeur': 3.3, 'titre': 'La cybersÃ©curitÃ© et le gestionnaire', 'sigle': 'TECH 20701', 'trimestre': 'H2005'}]
```

I tried this :

```
tableau = info.groupby(["Cours","Trimestre"])[["Valeur"]].mean()
```

but the answer is : 
'list' object has no attribute 'groupby'

Answer (score 0):

You first need create a DataFrame.You can use [`pd.DataFrame.from_dict`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.from_dict.html):

```
df=pd.DataFrame.from_dict(my_list)
print(df)
```

---

**Output**

```
  matricule               nom note valeur  \
0  22000803      Boyer,AndrÃ©   C+    2.3   
1  22000829    Keighan,Maylis   A+    4.3   
2  22000869       Lahaie,Lyes   B+    3.3   
3  22000973   Conerardy,Rawaa   B+    3.3   
4  22001034  Naftanaila,Carla   B+    3.3   

                                   titre       sigle trimestre  
0  La cybersÃ©curitÃ© et le gestionnaire  TECH 20701     H2005  
1  La cybersÃ©curitÃ© et le gestionnaire  TECH 20701     H2005  
2  La cybersÃ©curitÃ© et le gestionnaire  TECH 20701     H2005  
3  La cybersÃ©curitÃ© et le gestionnaire  TECH 20701     H2005  
4  La cybersÃ©curitÃ© et le gestionnaire  TECH 20701     H2005
```

---

where `my_list` is your list:

```
my_list=[{'matricule': '22000803', 'nom': 'Boyer,AndrÃ©', 'note': 'C+', 'valeur': 2.3, 'titre': 'La cybersÃ©curitÃ© et le gestionnaire', 'sigle': 'TECH 20701', 'trimestre': 'H2005'},
 {'matricule': '22000829', 'nom': 'Keighan,Maylis', 'note': 'A+', 'valeur': 4.3, 'titre': 'La cybersÃ©curitÃ© et le gestionnaire', 'sigle': 'TECH 20701', 'trimestre': 'H2005'},
 {'matricule': '22000869', 'nom': 'Lahaie,Lyes', 'note': 'B+', 'valeur': 3.3, 'titre': 'La cybersÃ©curitÃ© et le gestionnaire', 'sigle': 'TECH 20701', 'trimestre': 'H2005'},
 {'matricule': '22000973', 'nom': 'Conerardy,Rawaa', 'note': 'B+', 'valeur': 3.3, 'titre': 'La cybersÃ©curitÃ© et le gestionnaire', 'sigle': 'TECH 20701', 'trimestre': 'H2005'},
 {'matricule': '22001034', 'nom': 'Naftanaila,Carla', 'note': 'B+', 'valeur': 3.3, 'titre': 'La cybersÃ©curitÃ© et le gestionnaire', 'sigle': 'TECH 20701', 'trimestre': 'H2005'}]
```

---

Now you can use `groupby`: **You can only group by column labels that are present in the columns (Course is not present)**

```
df_means=df.groupby(['matricule','trimestre'],as_index=False).valeur.mean()
print(df_means)
```

**Output:**

```
  matricule trimestre  valeur
0  22000803     H2005     2.3
1  22000829     H2005     4.3
2  22000869     H2005     3.3
3  22000973     H2005     3.3
4  22001034     H2005     3.3
```